# non clustered index for 100 millions records in a table or pratitions

Tags: database, indexing, db2, query-optimization

I have a table  in IBM DB2 which contains more than 100 million records . Database was made 13 years ago and is not partitioned . Searching data and creating joins with this table takes huge amount of time .What should be proper approach to optimize searching and joins .
1. Using Non Clustered Index and searching via indexes .
2. Partitioning Table 
3. or any other efficient approach.

I would like thanks in advance for your valuable time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

A "proper" approach is, of course, subjective. It's usually a trade-off, and the things most people trade off are the cost of implementing the change, the cost of maintaining the change, and the performance of the solution.

In all cases, I recommend gathering metrics, and agreeing your target - otherwise, you risk continuously optimizing beyond the point the business really needs. Typically, this means creating a representative test environment, with representative data. You then run the queries as they are today, and measure their performance. Finally, you agree (with whoever is paying the bills) what the minimum and optimum targets are. Once you reach that target - stop!

By far the cheapest solution is to optimize your queries, which often means creating indices. Depending on your queries, this can sometimes take just a few hours, and doesn't require any ongoing maintenance.

The next thing to do is to look at server configuration - tuning the memory allocation and disk strategy can do wonders, and [making sure the database statistics are up to date.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001980.html) These tasks usually require 2 or 3 people to work together, and you may need to set up regular maintenance tasks.

If that doesn't do the job, consider improving the hardware. If your database server is as old as the database (13 years), it's quite possible that your mobile phone has better performance characteristics than your server. It's much cheaper to improve the hardware than it is to go to the next steps.

If hardware doesn't solve the problem, consider de-normalizing your data. For instance, if you are running lots of queries joining your large table to other large tables, consider creating a de-normalized table with all the data you need to fulfill that query. This is expensive, both from a development point of view (you have to work out how to maintain the denormalized data, how to make sure all the queries still work), and from a maintenance point of view - the additional complexity will make all enhancements and bug fixes harder.

If denormalizing doesn't work, partitioning is the next most expensive solution. This is a fairly drastic solution, because as far as I know, there's no "out of the box" solution to glue your front-end applications into the partitioning logic. So, pretty much every piece of code that needs to interact with the database needs to understand the partitioning logic, and a bug in any one place will break every other component that interacts with that data.

Comment: Thanks Sir , though late to thanks , but your suggestion helped me a lot .